# Syncronize intellij idea project with git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I'm trying to grasp a concept of GIT and how can I use it myself. I have several projects that I would like to work on at least two computers. My office laptop is Windows based and I have repositories for each project setup at bitbucket Dont have any problems committing changes from Windows. I have Linux based computer at home where I cloned my projects from bitbucket However, when I make changes to projects at home and then commit them, intellij idea keeps giving me a message that I need to insert github credentials So, I cannot commit any changes to bitbucket even though in Git->Repository->Remotes only bitbucket reps shown. I suspect I have some misconfiguration in linux intellij What can be wrong?

Comment: mark the answer as solved if you found the solution. Happy Coding.

Comment: have to wait for two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, The dialogue that asked to insert Git username and email was actually designed for local repository. I just inserted the name and email and everything works now.